# VBS logon script that runs only for certain users

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am working on a script to migrate users to a new print server. That script is great. I would like to create a addition to that script to only do users that username starts with certain charachters though. I am trying to find a solution that does not slow down the users that accounts dont start with those specific characters though. Other info: all of our users are already mapped to said login script but the printer migration portion is "REM"'d out till i get this portion done. Setting up a test bed of certain users.

basically 
if %USERNAME% begins with "fu"
    run printer migration script
else
    do nothing

I would like this to be a vbs script. Users are running windows 7. not sure if powershell would be better or quicker at this so it is a possibility if it would be more seamless. 
and as always thank you in advance for any information.

edits-

```
 Dim user,shell,reg, objShell
 Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


 Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set reg = WScript.CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

 user = shell.Environment("USER").Item("USERNAME")
 reg.Pattern = ["^fu"] <-------not sure if this is correct. But it doesnt give me a syntax error when i do this
 If reg.Execute(user).Count > 0 Then
    objShell.Run "printer_migration.vbs"
 End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already know that the current user name can be accessed via the environment variable `%USERNAME%`, you just have to compare that to your string. I'll use a regular expression to match the start:

```vbscript
Dim user,shell,reg

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set reg = WScript.CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

user = shell.Environment("USER").Item("USERNAME")
reg.Pattern = "^fu"
If reg.Execute(user).Count > 0 Then
    Rem this user matches the pattern
End If
```

Comment: Maybe i am missing something. So what you have here is the variables listed. you set the shell. Then let it know we are using regular expressions. from there we declare that "user" will get the enviromental variable for the current user and the one we are interested in is the "USERNAME" . From there we are doing a pattern match using regular expressions for '^fu" why is the "^" there? At this point we desire to use an if statement to declare we will run the comparison on the user and at this point idk what happens here. I assume if we run the comparison we get a boolean output

Comment: I guess the question is where do i declare that i want to run something if reg.Execute(user).Count < 0

Comment: @JustinYoder you would enter your processing logic for printer mapping inside that `If` statement replacing the `REM THIS USER MATCHES THE PATTERN` comment. or you can put a call to run your other script from there. like `Shell.run cscript.exe "C:\somevbsfile.vbs"`

Comment: @JustinYoder yes it's as ssaviers described. The reason the `^` is there in the regular expression is that that indicates a match for the beginning of the string (which you said is what you wanted). A regex match for `fu` alone would match the user name `funk` as well as `dafunk`, but `^fu` will only match `funk`.

Comment: I have added everything relevent to what i want it to do but i am getting a sytax error right where the pattern to match is. e.g. '^fu' not sure what i am doing wrong there ive tried double quoting it to no avail

Comment: Well double quotes make more sense so I edited it. Are you sure the error is on the line that assigns the pattern and not the line that executes it?

Comment: figured it out required me to surround that with [ ] brackets

Comment: Surround which part? Can you post the changed line?